# Математические правила для генерирования звука плавно нарастающей частоты

Tags: математика, аудио

Я пишу программу, которая генерирует WAV-файл, который содержит плавно меняющийся звук от частоты `seq1` до `seq2`, частотой дискретизации `sampleRate = 44100` и длинной `n` секунд. Необходимо найти формулу, по которой вычислять частоту текущего отрезка длинной в одно полное колебание звука, а так же общее количество отрезков frame.

Текущая частота - `seq = k1 * x + seq1`, где `k1` - скорость роста частоты, `x` - порядковый номер отрезка в одно полное колебание;

Число семплов на отрезок - `spt = sampleRate/seq = sampleRate/(k1*x+b);`

P.S. В принципе, можно упростить, отбросив начальную частоту, и считать по формуле `spt=(sampleRate/k1)/x`

Насколько я понимаю, количество отрезков и прирост частоты от отрезка к отрезку должно выводиться из уравнения

[image: \int_{0}^{frame}\frac{sampleRate}{k1*x+b} dx]

Но я точно не уверен.

Пожалуйста, помогите извлечь количество отрезков и скорость прироста частоты.

```
int main() {
    ofstream out("test.wav", ios::binary);

    int time = 30;
    waveHeaderInit(2, 44100, 16, time);
    waveData = new char[waveHeader.subchunk2Size];
    int sequence = 100;
    volatile float phase;
    volatile int16_t sample;

    int maxAmplitude = pow(2, waveHeader.bitsPerSample - 1) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < time * waveHeader.sampleRate; i++) {
        int spt = waveHeader.sampleRate / sequence;
        phase = (i % spt) / float(spt);
        sample = sin(PI*phase)*maxAmplitude;
        for (int channel = 0; channel < waveHeader.numChannels; channel++) {
            ((int16_t*)waveData)[i*waveHeader.numChannels + channel] = sample;
        }
    }

    out.write((char*)&waveHeader, sizeof(waveHeader));
    out.write(waveData, waveHeader.subchunk2Size);
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так вы хотите построить с "нуля" звук, или добавить эффекты в готовый?

Comment: Постарайтесь не задавать "двойных" вопросов.

Comment: f(частота, Гц) = 1/ T (Т - период в секундах).

Comment: Грубо можно записать f(t) = f0 +  (f1 - f0)* ((t - t0)/(t1 - t0)) как уравнение линии, если частоту хотите увеличивать линейно. (из общего уравнения линии).

Comment: Если вы хотите построить "синусоиду" то  f(t) = f0 + (f1 - f0)* ((t - t0)/(t1 - t0))  преобразуется в `sin(t*k*f(t))` - подставляете первую формулу в sin, ну а k - будет скорее всего 2*pi/sample_rate.

Comment: Мне нужен просто звук с плавно нарастающей частотой. Попытка решения вопроса "в лоб" - два вложенных цикла, в первом меняется частота через 0.1 сек, во втором производится запись - дала результат в виде "рваного" звука, поэтому решил заморочиться с изменением длинны волны "на лету"

Comment: Стройте синусоиду с наращиванием частоты, как показано выше.

Comment: Синусоиду я и так строю, вопрос в том, насколько поднимать частоту после записи колебания, чтобы частота плавно возрастала.

Comment: Задать частоту в аргументе синусоиды. `sin(2*pi*t*f(t))`

Comment: Почти так и делаю. Я правильно понял, что Вы предлагаете вместо того, чтобы полностью записать такт звука, а потом увеличивать частоту, "на лету" менять "длинну" синусоиды?

Comment: Да. Потому что не попадёте в такт и будет рватся. Очень сложно описать формулу что б попасть втакт (не представляю как).

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Ну... если в два раза то так sin(PI*phase*(1 + i/waveHeader.sampleRate) ) если не в 2 раза... то домножить второе слагаемое на (коефициент-1) –

Comment: сделал так:
 double deltaSeq = (endSequence - startSequence) / double(time * waveHeader.sampleRate); после чего в конце цикла
  sequence += deltaSeq;

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to play a fixed frequency sound using Python](https://askubuntu.com/q/202355/3712)

Answer (score 3):

Увеличивайте частоту медленно с экспоненциальной скоростью.
Монотонный звук это `A*sin(2Pi*B*t)`. Заменяем константу **B** на экспонету `B:=C*Exp[D*t]`.

```
C*Exp[D*t0]==seq0
C*Exp[D*t1]==seq1
---
D=Ln[seq1/seq0]/(t1-t0)
C=seq0*((seq0/seq1)^(t0/(t1-t0)))
```

Получаем `A*sin(2Pi*C*Exp[D*t]*t)`. Упрощаем `t0=0, t1=T`.Результат:

```
 A*sin(2Pi*seq0*((seq1/seq0)^(t/T))*t)
```